# Windows - Get current file size when file is still being written

Tags: windows

Does anyone know how to get the current size of a file on Windows while the file is still being written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, when a file is actively being appended to by a process, the file size often appears as 0 bytes when the file is viewed using the File explorer GUI, or via the command line 'dir' command.

However, if you right-click on the file using file explorer, and use examine the 'general' tab, the current file size and current file size on disk is displayed.